# Adjusting height, width, and resolution for png

Tags: r, plot, density-plot

I am trying to fit 6 graphs into one frame. I am having difficulty setting appropriate width, height and resolution. Can anyone explain to me the logic behind these settings? I need a good resolution.

```
png("M_F2.png", width = 7, height =7, units = 'in', res = 600)
```

Comment: What sort of graphs? What is an 'appropriate width'? What is a 'good resolution'? You might as well have asked what is our favourite colour! Have you taken a look at the help in `?layout` or the graphics options in `?par`? as a starting point?

Comment: From the question I assume 7x7 inches is a good width and 600 dpi a good resolution.  Presumably M_F2.png isn't being rendered on screen or paper to these specifications.

Answer (score 0):

I was changing several combinations, sometime works sometimes does not. one frame of the picture code is

```
`

plot(density(Width), ylab="Proportion", xlab="Width (mm)", ylim=c(0,0.07), xlim=c(60,140), main="",
     lwd=2, col=1, lty=1)

attach(Port_N_12 )
lines(density(Width), col="red",lty=2, lwd=2)
abline(v=89.91, col="grey", lty=4, lwd=2)

legend(60, 0.07,legend=c("At sea","Port"),seg.len=3,
       lty=c(1:2), title="",text.col=c(1:2),
       ncol=1, bty ="n", bg="green", col=c(1,2),lwd=2)
text(140,0.065, "2012", font=2)
```

`

and I need to fit 6 of them using 3 column and 2 rows